# Elasticsearch mongodb river tailable curosr issue

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch, mongodb and elasticsearch mongodb river

> https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb

When I observe my mongodb logs the river keeps on querying the oplog of my elasticsearch even when it is not indexing the documents and also it is taking long time to finish indexing the collection.

Any guidance on the above mentioned issues?

Answer (score 0):

elasticsearch mongodb river [1] uses the recommended way [2] to query tailable cursor in MongoDB

If you observe extra query in oplog.rs I'd suggest to try contacting MongoDB and especially MongoDB Java Driver [3].

I am happy to fix any issue in elasticsearch mongodb river.

[1] - https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb/blob/master/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/river/mongodb/MongoDBRiver.java#L1326
[2] - https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/master/examples/ReadOplog.java#L47
[3] - https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver